# Привести все слова в DataFrame в начальную форму

Tags: python, база-данных

С использованием Pymorphy2 привести все слова к начальной форме в датафрейме.

`First  Sec
My  Я вчера видел цветы красных цветов`

Нужно каждое слово в столбце `Sec` привести в начальную форму и вернуть обратно

то есть на выходе нужно получить:

`First  Sec
My  я вчера видеть цвета красных цветок`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поставить слово в начальную форму используйте

```py
morph.parse(word)[0].normal_form
```

где morph - pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

normal_form возвращает начальную форму слова